# How to sync two databases data in django tests?

Tags: python, django, database, django-testing

I am using two databases, `default` and `readonly`, as the name suggests that `default` is used to write and `readonly` used to read. Till this, it works fine.

and Then in my models, I changed database managers for reading from particular database data, as I cannot use Django routers due to the complexity.

in models, there is a Manger for `readonly` database, like this:

```
objects = models.Manger()
readonly = objects.db_manager("readonly")
```

And In views, I am using `Model.readonly.all()`. So far so good. Problem comes in while testing views.

```
def test_event_view():
    e = Event.objects.create(self.event_data)
    url = reverse('event-detail', kwargs={'slug': e.slug})
    response = self.client.get(f"{url}?state=Florida")
    self.assertOK(response) # Should be 2 == status_code/100
```

Because view is reading from `readonly` and this test is creating an object in `default`, so it says event does not exist on `readonly` database. SO my question is how to handle this situation?